# Xcode 8 Swift 3.0 : Parse error - Could not read PHPMailer code

Tags: php, email, swift3, xcode8, phpmailer

I have a problem on xcode 8.

In PHP, I'm using PHPMailer to send the email. my PHP code like below.

**send.php**

```
<?php
    require 'database/connect.php';
    global $connect;
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    require 'PHPMailer-master2/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if ( isset($_POST['data1']) && isset($_POST['data2']))
    {
        $data1 = $_POST['data1'];
        $data2 = $_POST['data2'];

        $sql        = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data1 = '$data1' AND data2='$data2'";
        $result     = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            }

            $output = array('message' => '1');
            echo json_encode($output);
            $add = "INSERT INTO table (data1, data2)
                               VALUES ('$data1','$data2')
            ";
            $run = mysqli_query($connect,$add);
            $mail = new PHPMailer;                             
            $mail->isSMTP();                                       
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                
            $mail->Username = 'gmail.com';               
            $mail->Password = '******';                            
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
            $mail->Port = 587;                                     
            $mail->setFrom('sender@mail.com', 'sender');  
            $mail->addAddress('receiver@mail.com','receiver');
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
            $mail->Subject = 'Test';
            $mail->Body    = 'Test';
            $mail->AltBody = 'Test';
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo json_encode([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo
            ]);
        } else {
            $status   = array();
            $status[] = array('status' => '1');
        }

        $output = array('message' => '1', 'status' => $status);
        echo json_encode($output);
        exit();
            // End sending email
            exit();

        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {}
    }
?>
```

I managed to send the data to the server and send email to receiver using code above.

The only issue I'm facing right now is in xcode. It says:

> Parse error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct
>   format.

[image]

Xcode can't read my PHPMailer code in PHP file, that cause my swift 3.0 code to execute an **Catch** statement instead of **message == '1'** statement. My swift code as below.

**post.swift**

```
@IBAction func sendApplyMovement(_ sender: Any) {
            let url             = URL(string: "http://localhost/send.php")
            let session         = URLSession.shared
            let request         = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod  = "POST"
            let valueToSend     = "data1=&data2"
            request.httpBody    = valueToSend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let myAlert         = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Sure ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let cancel          = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
            let okaction        = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:
                {
                    action in

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                else {
                            do {
                                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
                                {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        let message   = Int(json["message"]!)
                                        let status    = Int(json["status"]!)

                                        if(message == 1){
                                            if(status == 1){
                                                print("Success")
                                                let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                                                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                                                let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: myViewController)
                                                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                                                appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                                                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Sent !", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                                myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                                                navigationController.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                                return
                                            }

                                        }
                                        else {return}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch let parseError { print("Parse error: \(parseError.localizedDescription)") }
                }
            })
            task.resume()

            }
            )
            myAlert.addAction(okaction)
            myAlert.addAction(cancel)
            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Is there something that I need to modify in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
```

This implies that the data you're getting is in JSON format, but your PHPMailer code does this:

```
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

which does not return JSON code, so I'm not surprised you're having trouble parsing it. You posted this question before but it was very unclear - you made it sound like Xcode couldn't open your PHP file, not that you couldn't parse a response; it's a Swift runtime error, not an Xcode error.

Return your response in JSON format and you might have more success, something like:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo json_encode([
        'status' => false,
        'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo
    ]);
} else {
    echo json_encode([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'Message sent'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Ok. i'll try it first . . .

Comment: Error "Parse error" gone, but still cannot execute UIAlert inside message == 1

Comment: Just read the code - it's looking for a value of '1' inside the `message` element, but I stuck a string in there - you just need to make sure you output and input line up - Try changing your code to `if (json["status"])` so it will look at the `status` element instead.

Comment: Okay . i'll try it first . .

Comment: Check your values - set a breakpoint, make sure your variables contain what you expect. I don't know Swift's rules for type coercion, so make sure your cast to an integer works on a boolean JSON value. If you have trouble making it match, you can always change the values that the PHP script returns.